# Adding asterisk (*) to configuration file with Ansible lineinfile module

Tags: ansible, aix, ansible-2.x, syslog

I am trying to write a playbook to add log forwarder lines to syslog.conf on AIX.

The tasks looks like this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    log_servers:
      - "auth.info\t@10.10.10.100"
      - "*.info\t@log.example.com"

- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/syslog.conf
    regexp: '^{{item}}'
    line: '{{item}}'
  loop: "{{log_servers}}"
```

The first line is inserted with no issues, but I get a Python exception when the second line is encountered because of the leading asterisk.

An asterisk can be anywhere else in the line, but not at the start of the line. And escaping with a backslash (`\*.info\t@log.example.com`) causes a JSON parsing error, and a double backslash (`\\*.info\t@log.example.com`) just inserts a backslash at the front of the line.

Any advice on how to get around this?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is coming from the fact that you are trying to use the same string for a regex (where you need to escape the star) and for the line to add (where you don't need to escape the star).

There is a way to resolve this, though, it is to use the builtin [`regex_escape` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_escape_filter.html).

And so, your two task should become:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    log_servers:
      - "auth.info\t@10.10.10.100"
      - "*.info\t@log.example.com"

- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/syslog.conf
    regexp: '^{{ item | regex_escape() }}'
    line: '{{ item }}'
  loop: "{{ log_servers }}"
```

Comment: That worked!  I tried regex_escape, but I put it in the 'line:' line.  That resulted in a bunch of backslashes in front of every non-alpha character.  Not what I wanted.  Thanks!